# Prove: $\lim_{m→∞} \int_0^a (a^{2m} - x^{2m})^{\frac {1}{2m}} dx = a^2$

Tags: geometry, definite-integrals

Working on Desmos , I found that the equation $x^{2m} + y^{2m} = a^{2m}$ generates a square of side $2a$ centred at the origin as $m→∞$, $m$ being a positive integer. Graphically it is easy to verify the following result on the area of the square (which is $4a^2$):
$$\lim_{m→∞} \int_0^a (a^{2m} - x^{2m})^{\frac {1}{2m}} dx = a^2$$ 
But is it possible to prove this result analytically? The integral is posing great difficulty to be solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After letting $t=x/a$, we have that
$$ \int_0^a (a^{2m} - x^{2m})^{\frac {1}{2m}} dx=a^2\int_0^1 (1 - t^{2m})^{\frac {1}{2m}} dt.$$
Moreover, for $0\leq t\leq 1$,
$$1 - t^{2m}\leq (1 - t^{2m})^{\frac {1}{2m}}\leq 1$$
which implies that
$$1-\frac{1}{2m+1}=\int_0^1 (1-t^{2m}) dt\leq \int_0^1 (1 - t^{2m})^{\frac {1}{2m}} dt\leq \int_0^1 1dt=1.$$
Hence, by the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem),
$$\lim_{m\to \infty} \int_0^a (a^{2m} - x^{2m})^{\frac {1}{2m}} dx = a^2\lim_{m\to \infty} \int_0^1 (1 - t^{2m})^{\frac {1}{2m}} dt=a^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

The substitution $x=ay$ reduces the proof to the case $a=1$. I that case the integrand tend to $1$ at each point and it is bounded by the constant $1$ so the limit is $1$ by Bounded Convergnce Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote *"the integral is posing great difficulty to be solved".*

Don't worry : sooner or later, you will learn that
$$I_m=a^2\int_0^1 \left(1-t^{2 m}\right)^{\frac{1}{2 m}}\,dt=a^2\,\frac{\Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{2 m}\right)\, \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2 m}\right)}{2\, \Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{m}\right)}$$ where appears the gamma function. If you use the series expansion for large values of $m$, you should get,as an approximation,
$$I_m=a^2\left(1-\frac{\pi ^2}{24\, m^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^3}\right)\right)$$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached.